# How to split a list of strings after determined word without using modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys so how can I split this list into sublists using a key word `#` without using any modules:

my list:

```
['w1', 'w2', '#', 'w3', '#']
```

and I want this:

```
[['w1','w2', '#'],['w3', '#']]
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: What is the current status of your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate though the list and create sublists and append them

```
result = []
sub = []
for item in original_list:
    sub.append(item)
    if item == "#":
        result.append(sub)
        sub = []

print(result)
[['w1', 'w2', '#'], ['w3', '#']]
```

Answer (score 2):

With a module and a great way, you can use `groupby` from the `itertools` Python standard module library.

```
from itertools import groupby
li = ['w1', 'w2', '#', 'w3', '#']

delim = '#'

[list(g) + [delim] for k,g in groupby(li, lambda x: x == delim) if not k]
>> [['w1', 'w2', '#'], ['w3', '#']]
```

`groupby` makes an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable, the lambda function checks and groups by consecutive non-delimiters and the delimiter is filtered out by `if not k` from list criteria selection.

The list is then extended to include the delimiter for your output.

**Edit:** I just only realized it says without a module, but why would you want to do that especially if there are great libraries in Python and you do not have to reinvent the wheel. Oh well.

Without a module, you can refer to the other answers.